# Save Plot Options of Mathematica into a single variable

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

How can I save the numerous Plot options in Mathematica into a single variable

Comment: This? `myvar=SetOptions[Plot,PlotStyle->Red]`

Comment: `opts = Options[Plot]`

Answer (score 11):

As per [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19416/pass-list-of-options-to-plot3d),

```
opts = {PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red};
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Evaluate[opts]]
```